# Kendo UI & Angularjs: make grid inline editable

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

i've integrated kendo ui in angularjs following this guide: [Angular Kendo UI](http://kendo-labs.github.io/angular-kendo/#/)

Now i'd like to make my grid inline editable. In the angularjs controller i have:

```
gestionale.controller('mainController', function ($scope, $http) {

   $scope.products = new kendo.data.DataSource({
       transport: {
           read: {
               url: "api/Personale",
               dataType: "json"
           }
       },
   });
});
```

In the HTML page:

```
<div kendo-grid k-data-source="products" k-selectable="'row'" k-sortable="true" k-toolbar ='["create"]'
     k-columns='[
{ "field": "Nome", "title": "Nome"},
{ "field": "Cognome", "title": "Cognome"},
{ "field": "Cellulare", "title": "Cellulare" },
{ command: ["edit", "destroy"], title: "", width: "172px" }
 ]' k-editable="inline" style="height: 365px">
</div>
```

With this code the grid is correctly populated and i can see the edit and delete button but, when i click on the edit button, the row doesn't go in inline editing mode (when i click on the edit button there is a refresh of the page).

How can i get the inline editing mode?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you should define `k-editable` :

```
<div kendo-grid k-data-source="products" k-selectable="'row'" k-sortable="true" k-toolbar ='["create"]'
     k-columns='[
{ "field": "Nome", "title": "Nome"},
{ "field": "Cognome", "title": "Cognome"},
{ "field": "Cellulare", "title": "Cellulare" },
{ command: ["edit", "destroy"], title: "", width: "172px" }
 ]' k-editable='{"mode": "inline", "create": true, "update": false, "destroy": true}' style="height: 365px">
</div>
```

Comment: Also try this: `k-editable="true"`. And check This: [angularjs-starter](http://plnkr.co/edit/WwH69W?p=preview). good luck!

Comment: k-editable="true" make only one cell editable and works. I want the inline and in the kendo ui documentation i have seen that is available the editable = "inline" but doesn't work

Comment: Have you try the `k-editable='{"mode": "inline"}'` ?

Comment: It works!!! Why i must type the code in that mode instead of k-editable="inline"? For example to make the grid sortable i've type k-sortable="true" and works!!

Comment: because it's value can be a boolean or object. means `True` or `False` or `{"mode": "inline"}`.

Comment: Kendo UI actually distinguishes between true and "inline" (if you use a plain grid, you can use data-editable='inner'), so the problem is probably with angular-kendo

Comment: @LarsHöppner Thanks for sharing your knowledge, Yes I know that `data-editable='inner'` is correct (_and kendo can determine boolean, string, object, function..._) but I don't see anywhere in _angular-kendo_ the same syntax.